# Espresso OkHttp Idling Resource

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-espresso, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2 with RxJava2 Adapter in my app. In my Instrumentation Tests I often use `Thread.sleep(millis)` function to wait for retrofit operations to be ready and then do some view assertions.

In my tests I mock the responses by providing local json and xml files.

Now I would prefer not to wait for a specific time but somehow catch an event when all retrofit calls succeeded. I tried to use [Jake Whartons' OkHttp Idling Resource](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource) library. But I think it does not work for me. Before providing any code samples I would like to know:

1. Does the library work only for asynchronous calls when returning a `Call` object? Or does it also work together with RxJava?
2. Do I only have to call `Espresso.registerIdlingResources()` or shall I also call `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()` after that?
3. In my app I make a first retrofit call and if it is finished I make 10 other calls in a for loop. Will retrofit be idle between the calls? And do I have to implement my own Idling Resource workflow for my consecutive calls?

Comment: so your app does real calls to webservers returning real data? if possible i would suggest you mock away the webserver, this way you have lesser dependencies and can also test if your app sends the right calls at a certain time.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to write that I use mocks. Now I updated my post